# Как узнать количество данных, выбранных по запросу?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

При использовании библиотеки MysqlClient для Дельфи как узнать количество данных, выбранных по запросу `MySQLResult := MySQLClient.Query(com,true,ok)`, где сом-команда Select.

Comment: Вероятно у меня древняя версия MysqlClient.
В этом операторе  "count := (TMysqlClient.Table).RecordCount;" дельфи не признает  Table, пишет "неизвестный идентификатор".
Не подскажете, где можно скачать свежую версию MysqlClient 

Answer (score 1):

Ну в данной библиотеке есть не визуальный компонент, наследник стандартного класса - `TTable`.

Если вы умеете работать с базовым классом, то вам не должно составить особого труда посчитать строки в наборе данных( ниже псевдокод ):

```
count := (TMysqlClient.Table).RecordCount;
```

Опираясь на это, вы должны суметь самостоятельно получить количество строк в выведенном наборе.